# Manual Log Exception in Azure Mobile Center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I am using https://mobile.azure.com/ so I would like to know How can I do to log a manual exception?

Because I am using:

```
MobileCenter.Start("xxx-xx-xx-xx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true);
MobileCenter.SetEnabledAsync(true);
MobileCenterLog.Error("X1","x2",new Exception("Testing"));
```

and I can't see this exception in the portal.

any idea?

Comment: Log flows (within Mobile Center Analytics) are not enabled by default, you need to contact support via the intercom/chat button and ask them to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not yet supported by Mobile Center.

The API you are calling is for the SDK to emit traces in the console output, it is not an API meant to report anything to the server.

PS: `SetEnabledAsync(true)` is useless here, it is useful only if you previously disabled SDK with `false`, default value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I chat with tech support, and this feature is not available.